# Portable libraries, MVVM and how to abstract local database

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, mvvm, sql-server-ce, mvvm-light

I found this [great example of using MVVM and Portable libraries](https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=30d7e2f2bc3db6be&id=30D7E2F2BC3DB6BE!637) and found it very useful and I want start using it in my projects and solutions. I started to port my current Windows Phone app by this example that it would satisfy MVVM pattern. I am just not sure how to abstract local database like SQLCE.

My not-MVVM solution was something like this:

DataContext

```
public class ChallengeDataContext : DataContext
{
    public const string ConnectionString = "isostore:/challenges.sdf";

    public ChallengeDataContext(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    {
        this.Challenges = this.GetTable<Challenge>();
    }

    public Table<Challenge> Challenges { get; set; }
}
```

Repository

```
public class ChallengeRepository
{
    public static void Initialize()
    {
        using (ChallengeDataContext dc = new ChallengeDataContext(ChallengeDataContext.ConnectionString))
        {
            if (dc.DatabaseExists() == false)
            {
                dc.CreateDatabase();
                dc.SubmitChanges();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void SeedSampleData()
    {
        using (ChallengeDataContext dc = new ChallengeDataContext(ChallengeDataContext.ConnectionString))
        {
            if (dc.DatabaseExists() != false && dc.Challenges.Count() == 0)
            {
                var challenge = new Challenge("Testing", 3, ChallengeKind.Writting, false);
                dc.Challenges.InsertOnSubmit(challenge1);
                dc.SubmitChanges();
            }
        }
    }

    public Challenge GetChallengeRandomly(int difficulty, ChallengeKind kind)
    {
        using (ChallengeDataContext dc = new ChallengeDataContext(ChallengeDataContext.ConnectionString))
        {
            var challenge = (from ch in dc.Challenges
                             where ch.Difficulty == difficulty && ch.Kind == kind && ch.Shown == false
                             select ch).FirstOrDefault();
            return challenge;
        }

    }

    public void SaveChallenge(Challenge challenge)
    {
        using (ChallengeDataContext dc = new ChallengeDataContext(ChallengeDataContext.ConnectionString))
        {
            dc.Challenges.InsertOnSubmit(challenge);
            dc.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }

    public void UpdateChallengeShownAttribute(int id, bool shown)
    {
        using (ChallengeDataContext dc = new ChallengeDataContext(ChallengeDataContext.ConnectionString))
        {
            var challenge = (from ch in dc.Challenges
                             where ch.Id == id
                             select ch).FirstOrDefault();

            if (challenge != null)
            {
                challenge.Shown = shown;
                dc.SubmitChanges();
            }
        }
    }

    public void UpdateChallengeShownAttribute(int difficulty, ChallengeKind kind, bool shown)
    {
        using (ChallengeDataContext dc = new ChallengeDataContext(ChallengeDataContext.ConnectionString))
        {
            var challenges = from ch in dc.Challenges
                             where ch.Kind == kind && ch.Difficulty == difficulty
                             select ch;

            foreach (var challenge in challenges)
            {
                challenge.Shown = shown;
            }
            dc.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Challenge class

```
[Table(Name = "Challenges")]
public class Challenge
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true,IsDbGenerated=true)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public int Difficulty { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public ChallengeKind Kind { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public bool Shown { get; set; }

    public Challenge()
    {
    }

    public Challenge(string name, int difficulty, ChallengeKind kind, bool shown)
    {
        Name = name;
        Difficulty = difficulty;
        Kind = kind;
        Shown = shown;
    }
}
public enum ChallengeKind
{
    Writting,
    Telling,
    Pantomime
}
```

I know basics and It's not problem to create interface but I am not sure how to change model class that can be use in all projects (I can change attributes to DataContract and DataMember but how to use it then with SQLCE?). Then in which project I have to implementing repository? The code would be same in all platforms but I think Windows 8 doesn't use SQLCE. So how to count with this? Thanks for help

Comment: AFAIK you just can't use that in WinRT/WP8 app when you're referencing `SQLCE`. The best you could possibly do is target the lowest common denominator, like SQLite which is supported on both WinRT and WP8 (I don't know about WP7 though...). Other than that you'd have to make separate libraries.

Comment: Thanks for comment. I was searching and I think I found possible solution with SQLite for both WP. But I was thinking and I implement separate libraries for access to databases.